# Custom Calendar Control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is it possible to make control like this or change date time picker to something like this that has drop down lists?

Like Datagrid View having three ComboBoxes in each columns

adding combobox would not be a problem but populating datagrid view with calendar is a problem

or there is any library for that[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question :s

Comment: Is this for Win Forms or WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few scheduler controls for WPF (mostly commercial). You should be able to customize most of those to your needs by editing their templates.

- http://wpfschedule.codeplex.com/ (free)
- http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ScheduleWPF/
- http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/scheduleview.aspx
- http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Scheduler/
- http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/wpfelements/controls/wpf-scheduler
- http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/wpf/schedule